# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Error

Tags: swift

I am making a sprite based game. While applying physics to my coin sprites, I have begun to encounter this error. Any suggestions on how to avoid it ?

```
@objc func spawnEnemy(){
    enemy = childNode(withName: "enemy") as? SKSpriteNode
    coin = childNode(withName: "coin") as? SKSpriteNode
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

and later

```
 for coin in sprites{
    if coin.name == "coin"{
        coin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: enemy.size)
        coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.coin
          coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =           PhysicsCategory.player
        coin.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        coin.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        }
}
```

Comment: Please check if there is a typo in your .sks file. And please make sure that the SKNode with name "coin" is a SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 0):

You should always safely unwrap optional values by using "if let" or "guard let"

by using if let :

```
   if let coin = coin , let name = coin.name { 
    // you can use "coin" or "name" safely here
   }else{
     // "coin" or "name" is nil
   }
```

by using guard let :

```
   guard let coin = coin , let name = coin.name  else { 
     // "coin" or "name" is nil
    return
    }
    //you can use "coin" or "name" safely here
```